# How did [a-z] match é?

Tags: regex, grep, locale

Wow, this actually matched an `é`.  What happened here?  I would like it to not matching anything other than typically lower case letters.

```
$ echo "frappé"|egrep -E "^[a-z]+$"
frappé
```

egrep (GNU grep) 2.16 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I just tried this on my mac, and the expression did not match anything, the way it should. On what system are you running it?

Comment: Doesn't match for me: https://www.regex101.com/r/zD2lX8/1

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/zD2lX8/2

Comment: I got a reply from Eric Blake at redhat ... "your current locale is set up to include letters outside of the 26 ascii
bytes.  Run with LC_ALL=C in the environment to get the well-defined
behavior you seem to want, and note that POSIX states that range
expressions in regular expressions are undefined in non-C locales,
precisely because some tools use all collation elements that 'sort'
would place in the range, while other tools use 'rational range
expression' and treat the range as if it were ASCII instead of the
current locale."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your [locale](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html) setting tells `egrep`/`grep -E` how to collate the `[a-z]` character range.

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ echo "frappé" | egrep '^[a-z]+$'
# no match

$ export LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8
$ echo "frappé" | egrep '^[a-z]+$'
frappé
```

Named character classes can be used to match characters with diacritics in spite of the locale:

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ echo "frappé" | egrep '^[[:lower:]]+$'
frappé
```

Comment: The only reason the basic mode doesn't appear to match is because in the basic mode, `+` only matches a literal `+`. `echo "frappé" | grep '^[a-z]*$'` does match. (I don't know about `-P`, that's disabled in my grep.)

Comment: Good point about -G, `echo "é" | LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 grep -G '^[a-z]$'` matches.